# how to display uploaded image file name from database when going to edit(Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

I know how to upload image to database and show the image name in the view. Now I need to know how I display image name when going to Edit that Database.

My Create_Edit_Floor.php ---->

```
<tr><!--Edit by Yesh | Upload floor image-->
        <td width='20%'>Floor Map <span class='star'> * </span></td>
        <td width='5%'>:</td> 
        <td width='20%'><?=form_upload('emergency_img')?></td>
        <td><span id="error"><?=isset($upload_file_error) ? $upload_file_error : ''; ?></span></td>
</tr><!--Edit by Yesh-->
```

I think, I need to pass something inside the `<?form_upload?>`

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: do you want to display the image name from database while editing?

Comment: if yes then you can display the image after <?=form_upload('emergency_img')?> from database.

Comment: Yes, I need to display image name while going to edit. How?? I do it??

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are saving images into db you're doing it wrong.

then, if you really need to save them inside db, you have to run a query to the db to get the images as SQL result and then show them like (i guess you are saving the binary image into db)

`<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row->image); ?>" />`

I really suggest you to not save images into the db, usually i save the filename but not the image itself, cause images should be linked to let the browser cache them

just my 2 cents